# Equal Roots in Trigonometric Equations

Tags: trigonometry, polynomials

If the quadratic equation $x^2+2cos(4\theta)=4xsin(\theta+\frac{\pi}{4})$ has equal roots in $x$ , find the general value of $\theta$ in radians.

Comment: hint: solve the quadratic equation and set the discriminante equal to zero

Comment: I did and was left with the unsimplifiable(or i just dont see it) 6sin^2(theta) - 6sin^4(theta) + 2sinthetacostheta = 0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your discriminate is given by $$1-\cos(4\theta)+\sin(2\theta)$$ and can be factorized in to $$2\sin(\theta)\cos(\theta)(2\sin(2\theta)+1)$$
can you solve this?
$$\cos(4\theta)=8\, \left( \cos \left( \theta \right)  \right) ^{4}-8\, \left( \cos \left( 
\theta \right)  \right) ^{2}+1$$
and $$1+8\cos(\theta)^4-8\cos(\theta)^2+\sin(2\theta)-1$$
this is $$8\cos(\theta)^2(1-\cos(\theta^2)+\sin(2\theta)$$
$$8\sin(\theta)^2\cos(\theta)^2+\sin(2\theta)$$

Comment: How did you simplify $1-cos4\theta$ into $2sin(2\theta)^2$

Comment: i have used the Addition formulas

Comment: Using addition formulas I got $1 - cos4\theta = 1-(cos^4\theta + sin^4\theta + 2sin^2\theta cos^2\theta)$ 
Could you tell me where I messed up?